# What is better way to save cart data on flutter?

Tags: flutter

i have flutter app, i want to store cart data on phone, what should i use,
SQFlite or SharedPreferences? Cart data contain multi array on single product

Answer (score 1):

While using `SharedPreferences` will reduce computing overhead and simplify code implementation, it has it's limitations. For instance, you can only store primitive key/value pairs so it wouldn't be suitable for storing complex data structures or large arrays. The other major disadvantage is that you can't search through it, you have to know the exact key you're looking for.

For a situation where there is no upper limit to the size of the cart you'd be better off storing the data in a database or in [internal storage](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) by writing your own cart data file.

Answer (score 1):

First Use `Maps<List<Product>>` for maintaining data in app, next to save it you can convert it to JSON and store as String in `SharedPreferences` as `cart`.
To retrieve just decode in `Map` and use.
Make sure decoding and encoding should be used as `async` and don't return any value, so user can continue with cart without interruption.

Answer (score 1):

Use [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)! You can store map, lists and any Dart object there. It is encrypted and it has WEB support!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the Provider package to store the state of your cart.